# Change Capture from DB2 to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, db2

I am trying to get all inserts, updates, deletes to a normalized DB2 database (hosted on an IBM Mainframe) synced to a Cassandra database. I also need to denormalize these changes before I write them to Cassandra so that the data structure meets my Cassandra model.
Searched on google but tools either lack processing support or streaming CDC support.
Is there any tool out there that can help me achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that no stock tool exists. What's the format of the CDC stream coming out? What queries do you need to run? Like any other Cassandra data modeling question, start with the queries you need to run and work backwards to the table structure(s).